# How do I override a parent control's IsEnabled setting for a child control in AvaloniaUI?

Tags: c#, wpf, avaloniaui

I have an .Net AvaloniaUI application.
I've got a series of nested controls/containers where the top level container has IsEnabled set to False. I need to have a button contained in a lower child container enabled.

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to override the parent containers **IsEnabled** setting in a child control.

**I am creating the following wrapper class:**

public class CustomButton : Button, IStyleable
{
Type IStyleable.StyleKey => typeof(Button);

```
static CustomButton()
{
    IsEnabledProperty.OverrideMetadata<CustomButton>(
        new StyledPropertyMetadata<bool>(defaultValue: default(bool),
                defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.Default,
            (control, e) =>
            {
                return true;
            }));
}
```

}

The button displays, but the on change event is not getting fired to override the **IsEnabledProperty**. The control's enable state is also controlled by **IsEffectiveEnabled**.

How do I set the IsEnabled property on this control?

Comment: I will admit to not having developed in Avalonia.  But if it is anything like WPF (which it is modeled after) then you should not be able to do this.  Disabling a parent element is *supposed* to disable all child elements.